# Arduino GSM Shield NET and STATUS led turn off after a few seconds

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

```
#include <GSM.h>

// PIN Number
#define PINNUMBER ""

// initialize the library instance
GSM gsmAccess;     // include a 'true' parameter to enable debugging
GSMScanner scannerNetworks;
GSMModem modemTest;

// Save data variables
String IMEI = "";

// serial monitor result messages
String errortext = "ERROR";

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("GSM networks scanner");
  scannerNetworks.begin();

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while (notConnected) {
    if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) {
      notConnected = false;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  // get modem parameters
  // IMEI, modem unique identifier
  Serial.print("Modem IMEI: ");
  IMEI = modemTest.getIMEI();
  IMEI.replace("\n", "");
  if (IMEI != NULL) {
    Serial.println(IMEI);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // scan for existing networks, displays a list of networks
  Serial.println("Scanning available networks. May take some seconds.");
  Serial.println(scannerNetworks.readNetworks());

  // currently connected carrier
  Serial.print("Current carrier: ");
  Serial.println(scannerNetworks.getCurrentCarrier());

  // returns strength and ber
  // signal strength in 0-31 scale. 31 means power > 51dBm
  // BER is the Bit Error Rate. 0-7 scale. 99=not detectable
  Serial.print("Signal Strength: ");
  Serial.print(scannerNetworks.getSignalStrength());
  Serial.println(" [0-31]");
}
```

Results:
When I run the program, I can see the "GSM networks scanner" message appear on my serial monitor, but it does not display anything else after that. Also, the NET and STATUS LEDs turn off after some few seconds when the program starts running. I already made the minor adjustments necessary for the Arduino Mega, and the power supply is temporarily from the USB port of my laptop connected to the Arduino Mega. I am using a SIM card that has been activated.

I think my program stops at this stage:

```
  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while (notConnected) {
    if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) {
      notConnected = false;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
```

P.S. when I run the program without inserting a SIM card, the NET and STATUS LEDs keep on working (NET is blinking, while STATUS remains ON)

I tried this program as well https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield#toc9
and it has the same problem (i.e. stops at the same stage as the previous program)

[image: Serial Monitor result]

[image: GSM shield STATUS and NET (LEDs) turn off after some few seconds]

Comment: It would be great if you could format you code properly and describing expected results.

Comment: @jsotola I edited the question to make things clearer

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:
To solve my GSM shield issue, I connected a 9 V battery to my Arduino as a supply instead of using my Laptop's USB cable (and I also tried a 12 V supply as well). Thankfully, it did work. In the case that that it does not work (after uploading the program), click on the 'restart' button found on the GSM shield. You can find the type of sources that I used to supply my Arduino & GSM shield in the image posted below. IT IS IMPORTANT TO MENTION THAT THE FOLLOWING PROGRAM WAS IMPLEMENTED TO CHECK IF THE GSM SHIELD IS WORKING (I tried the "GSM Networks Scanner" program that I have mentioned in my question initially, but it did not work and it was not necessary anyways. So, I used the 'GSM SMS' code directly and it worked fine)

This is the code that worked out with me:

```
#include <GSM.h>

#define PINNUMBER ""

// initialize the library instance
GSM gsmAccess; // include a 'true' parameter for debug enabled
GSM_SMS sms;

// char array of the telephone number to send SMS
// change the number 1-212-555-1212 to a number
// you have access to
char remoteNumber[20]= "Replace this text with a mobile number instead";  

// char array of the message
char txtMsg[200]="Hello World";

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communications
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Sender");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while(notConnected)
  {
    if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
  sendSMS();
}

void loop()
{
// nothing to see here
}

void sendSMS(){

  Serial.print("Message to mobile number: ");
  Serial.println(remoteNumber);

  // sms text
  Serial.println("SENDING");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Message:");
  Serial.println(txtMsg);

  // send the message
  sms.beginSMS(remoteNumber);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS(); 
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");  
}
```

[image: These are the different supplies that I used]